# Is this definition of exponentiation correct? (Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction)

Tags: arithmetic, definition, exponentiation

In chapter 2 of Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction, the author (Timothy Gowers) writes:

> Two elementary rules about raising numbers to powers are the following.
>
> **E1** $a^1 = a$ for any real number $a$.
>
> **E2** $a^{m+n} = a^m \times a^n$ for any real number $a$ and any pair of natural
>   numbers $m$ and $n$.

Then comes this example:

> Let us write $x$ for the number $2^{3/2}$. Then $x \times x = 2^{3/2} \times 2^{3/2}$ which, by **E2**, is $2^{3/2+3/2} = 2^3 = 8$.

But $3/2$ isn't a natural number! A similar example follows involving a negative powers, but those aren't natural either.

If this is a mistake, it may seem minor - but I want to be sure I haven't missed something.

Comment: $2^{3/2}$ is a real number.

Comment: You are correct to be skeptical.  The properties $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not enough to conclude that $2^{\frac{3}{2}}\times2^{\frac{3}{2}}=8$.  One would first need to extend $E_2$ to include rational numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, we could as they suggest write $x=2^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and conclude that $2^{\frac{3}{2}}\times2^{\frac{3}{2}}=x\times x=x^1\times x^1=x^2=\left(2^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^2$, and then use some additional property that $(a^{b})^c=a^{bc}$ (*which again only really works for positive real $a$*)

Comment: You're taking these quotes out of context. If one reads the whole passage, it's clear that the whole point of the example is to show how to give a meaningful value to expressions like $2^{3/2}$, so that the previous laws for exponents still apply.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $e^{m+n} = e^m \times e^n$ for any pair of **real** **numbers** $m$ and $n$. And, $a^{m+n} = a^m \times a^n$ for any **positive** real number $a$ and any pair of real numbers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Don't know why your book only said so for natural numbers..

Comment: This is guaranteed to be true for *positive* values of $a$ and real $m,n$.  Errors occur with negative $a$ and non-integer exponents.

Comment: Yes, I shall edit my answer.